# Vertical histograms not working

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my histogram program, I am getting it to print out the exact thing that I want it to, however it has some unusual spacing problems and I was wondering if anyone could help me out with how to avoid it.
this is what my output looks like, as you can see it has wrong spacing in all the ones before the 90-100 bracket.

[image]

What I want it to look like so there is no space at the bottom between the numbers and the asterisk:

```
*
*
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   * *
* * * *
* * * *
0 1 2 3
```

also can anyone recommend something to use instead of `system("Clear")` or `system("PAUSE")`?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void readExamMarks(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray, int& counter1, int& counter2, int&   counter3, int& counter4,int& counter5, int& counter6,int& counter7, int& counter8, int& counter9, int& counter10){

cout << "Please enter a set of exam marks to see a histogram for:" << endl;
int x = 0;

for( int idx = 0; idx < sizeOfArray; idx++){
    cin >> x;
     if((x >=0) && (x <= 100)){
            x = x/10;

            switch(x){
            case 1:
                counter1++;

                break;
            case 2:
                counter2++;
                break;
            case 3:
                counter3++;

                break;
            case 4:
                counter4++;
                break;
            case 5:
                counter5++;

                break;
            case 6:
                counter6++;
                break;
            case 7:
                counter7++;

                break;
            case 8:
                counter8++;
                break;
            case 9:
                counter9++;

                break;
            case 10:
                counter9++;
                break;

            }

            examMarks[idx] = x;
        }
             else{
             cout << "ERROR: Value must be in range [0...100], please enter a valid value\n"; 
         }
}
}


void printExamMarksDecade(){

    cout << setw(5) << "10-20  " << "21-30  " << "31-40  " <<"41-50  " << "51-60  " << "61-70  " << "71-80  " << "81-90  " << "91-100  ";
}

void printHisto(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray,int counter1, int counter2, int& counter3, int& counter4,int& counter5, int& counter6,int& counter7, int& counter8, int& counter9, int& counter10){
system("cls");

while(counter1 != 0 ){
    cout << setw(3) << "*" << endl;
    counter1--;
}
while(counter2 != 0 ){
    cout << setw(10) << "*" << endl;
    counter2--;
}
while(counter3 != 0 ){
    cout << setw(17) << "*" << endl;
    counter3--;
}
while(counter4 != 0 ){
    cout << setw(24) << "*" << endl;
    counter4--;
}
while(counter5 != 0 ){
    cout << setw(31) << "*" << endl;
    counter5--;
}
while(counter6 != 0 ){
    cout << setw(38) << "*" << endl;
    counter6--;
}
while(counter7 != 0 ){
    cout << setw(45) << "*" << endl;
    counter7--;
}
while(counter8 != 0 ){
    cout << setw(52) << "*" << endl;
    counter8--;
}
while(counter9 != 0 ){
    cout << setw(59) << "*" << endl;
    counter9--;
}
}

int main() 
{
int examMarks[30];
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
int counter3 = 0;
int counter4 = 0;
int counter5 = 0;
int counter6 = 0;
int counter7 = 0;
int counter8 = 0;
int counter9 = 0;
int counter10 = 0;

readExamMarks(examMarks, 30, counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4, counter5, counter6, counter7, counter8, counter9, counter10);
printHisto(examMarks, 30, counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4, counter5, counter6, counter7, counter8, counter9, counter10);
printExamMarksDecade();


system("PAUSE");
 }
```

Comment: please include the actual output and what you expect instead. we're not telepaths.

Comment: The output is in the imugur link, I will include a picture of what I want it to look like in an edit

Comment: I hope, you know something about arrays. But why, tell me, why are you use 10 counters instead of array of counters? Also, in 10 case you increase `counter9`, not `counter10`.

Comment: @soon Because I have not learnt about using an array of counters yet, so I do not know how to

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I have edited it to show what I want it to look like

Comment: Like @soon said, you are incrementing the wrong counter in `case 10`.

Answer (score 0):

A variable `counter` for each range is not really what you want to be doing, you just want one array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  // count array for brackets 0 to 10
  int *count = new int[11];
  // variable to store each mark read
  int mark;

  // Read in marks
  while (cin >> mark) {
    // Increment the count for the bracket the mark falls in 
    count[mark/10]++;
  }

  for (int i=0;i<11;i++) {
    cout << i << "\t| " << string(count[i],'*') << endl;
  }

}
```

This plots a horizontal histograms but shows the much simple way it should be done.

```
$ ./histogram.out < marks
0   | ******
1   | *********
2   | **********
3   | ************
4   | *********
5   | *****************
6   | ********
7   | *********
8   | ***
9   | ****
10  | *
```

You will have less headaches modifying this code, try increasing the number of brackets to 1000 in original code!

Comment: I am getting the error, No operand matches these << for the ones after '\t|'

Comment: @Thomas should have been double quotes `"\t| "`.

Comment: I don't what your issue is as the code is okay http://ideone.com/fNVs12 anyway the point isn't take my code a submit it as your coursework, my point is you are doing the wrong thing using a separate counter variable and a case statemete per bracket, use an array!